# Swift call random function

Tags: ios, swift, function

I got 3 different functions and I want to call one of these randomly.

```
    if Int(ball.position.y) > maxIndexY! {
        let randomFunc = [self.firstFunction(), self.secondFunction(), self.thirdFunction()]
        let randomResult = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomFunc.count)))
        return randomFunc[randomResult]
    }
```

With this code I call all functions, and the order is always the same. What can I do to just call one of these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the three functions are called (and in the same order) is since you are causing them to be called when you put them in the array.

This:

```
let randomFunc = [self.firstFunction(), self.secondFunction(), self.thirdFunction()]
```

Stores the return value of each function in the array since you are invoking them (by adding the '`()`').

So at this point `randomFunc` contains the return values rather than the function closures

Instead just store the functions themselves with:

```
[self.firstFunction, self.secondFunction, self.thirdFunction]
```

Now if you want to call the selected method do not return its closure but invoke it:

```
 //return randomFunc[randomResult] // This will return the function closure 

 randomFunc[randomResult]() // This will execute the selected function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if Int(ball.position.y) > maxIndexY! {

let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0...2)

if randomNumber == 0 {
    firstFunction()
} else if randomNumber == 1 {
    secondFunction()
} else if randomNumber == 2 {
    thirdFunction()
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I expect it should work

```
if Int(ball.position.y) > maxIndexY! {
    let randomFunc = [self.firstFunction, self.secondFunction, self.thirdFunction]
    let randomResult = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomFunc.count)))
    return randomFunc[randomResult]()
}
```